# Преобразование типа фрагмента

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, преобразование-типов

имеется следующий вопрос. Учу андроид программирование по книге, и там встретил следующий код:

```
MainActivity.java:

package asus.example.com.workout;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WorkoutDetailFragment frag = (WorkoutDetailFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag);
        frag.setWorkout(1);
    }
}

Workout.java:

package asus.example.com.workout;

public class Workout {
    public String name;
    public String description;
    public static final Workout[] workout = {
            new Workout("The Limb Loosener",
                    "5 Handstand push-ups\n10 1-legged squats\n15 Pull-ups"),
            new Workout("Core Agony",
                    "100 Pull-ups\n100 Push-ups\n100 Sit-ups\n100 Squats"),
            new Workout("The Wimp Special",
                    "5 Pull-ups\n10 Push-ups\n15 Squats"),
            new Workout("Strength and Length",
                    "500 meter run\n21 x 1.5 pood kettleball swing\n21 x pull-ups")
    };
    private Workout(String name, String description){
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }
}


WorkoutDetailFragment.java:

package asus.example.com.workout;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class WorkoutDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    private long workoutId;


    public WorkoutDetailFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_detail, container, false);
    }

    public void setWorkout(long workoutId) {
        this.workoutId = workoutId;
    }
}
```

Однако этот код выбивает ошибку:

> error: incompatible types: Fragment cannot be converted to
>   WorkoutDetailFragment

На строке

```
WorkoutDetailFragment frag = (WorkoutDetailFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag);
```

Не понимаю, в чем ошибка, вроде же есть приведение типов. В чем проблема и как исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
WorkoutDetailFragment frag = (WorkoutDetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag);
```

getFragmentMangager() возвращает android.app.Fragment класс, а у вас WorkoutDetailFragment наследуется от android.support.v4.app.Fragment.

Comment: благодарю, заработало. Получается в книге опечатка

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii, не факт, что опечатка. Может импорт в `WorkoutDetailFragment` на обычный фрагмент, не из библиотеки поддержки.